# What is the reason of <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML error

Tags: android

What is the reason of the below error in my log cat ?

```
06-28 21:05:55.850: I/System.out(19770): Thread-3337 calls detatch()
06-28 21:05:56.210: I/System.out(19770): Thread-3337 calls detatch()
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): Thread-3337 calls detatch()
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): Response : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <head>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <title>Web hosting, domain names, VPS - 000webhost.com</title>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <link href="/new_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): </head>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <script type="text/javascript">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): </script>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <script type="text/javascript">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): try {
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-10701068-1");
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): pageTracker._trackPageview();
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): } catch(err) {}</script>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <map name="map1">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <area shape=rect coords="325,60,440,94" href="http://www.000webhost.com/features" target="_parent" alt="Features" title="Features">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <area shape=rect coords="442,60,549,94" href="http://www.000webhost.com/order.php" target="_parent" alt="Order Now" title="Order Now">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <area shape=rect coords="550,60,659,94" href="http://www.000webhost.com/affiliate-program" target="_parent" alt="Affiliate Program" title="Affiliate Program">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <area shape=rect coords="660,60,770,94" href="http://www.000webhost.com/contact" target="_parent" alt="Contact Us" title="Contact Us">         
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): </map>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <body class="twoColFixRtHdr">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <SCRIPT SRC="http://creative.xtendmedia.com/matomy/cf/ply/ply.js?pubid=50792397&mid=c51681034&wid=c51531274&popup=1&popunder=1&size=320x480&pop_times=2&pop_frequency=3600&mm_delay=0&mm_back_delay=300&numOfTimes=3&duration=1&period=24hour&close=1&openNewTab=true" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://c.ctpsrv.com/ma.js?s=154926"></script>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <div id="container">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770):   <div id="header">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770):    <img src="/images/locale/EN/header.gif" width="780" height="119" border="0" usemap="#map1" />
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): </div>
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770):  
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <div id="sidebar1">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): <div align="center">
06-28 21:05:56.600: I/System.out(19770): </div>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     <table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="20%"><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/menu1.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="80%"><a class="rightmenu" href="http://www.000webhost.com/">Free Web Hosting</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/main1.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/" class="rightmenu">Premium Web Hosting</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/main5.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.000webhost.com/website-builder" class="rightmenu">Website Builder</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/templates_small.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.000webhost.com/templates/" class="rightmenu">Website Templates</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>     
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/directory_list_small.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.000webhost.com/directory/" class="rightmenu">Web Hosting Reviews</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>             
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/menu11.jpg" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.000webhost.com/affiliate-program" class="rightmenu">Affiliate Program</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><img src="/images/icons/menu13.gif" width="16" height="16" /></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.000webhost.com/forum/" class="rightmenu">Web Hosting Forum</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     </table>
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     <div align="center"><br />
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     <br />
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     <a href="http://www.000webhost.com/order.php"><img src="/images/locale/EN/signup.gif" width="183" height="75" border="0" /></a> 
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     <br />
06-28 21:05:56.605: I/System.out(19770):     <br />
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     </div>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): </div>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): <div id="mainContent">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="12%"><img src="/images/icons/upgrade.gif" width="48" height="48" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="88%"><h4>Free web hosting, no ads or banners!</h4></td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     </table>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):    <p>Can you imagine <b>free web hosting</b> service that has 99.9% uptime? Too good to be true? No more! <a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'>000webhost.com</a> has made the revolution, forget the stereotype that free hosting is unreliable.. Here is the proof: <a href='http://www.serviceuptime.com/users/monitoring.php?S=6c8ef11fcca35bab3d971cdce3d7179b' target='_blank'>uptime stats of 20 servers</a>. We beat your paid hosting provider!</p>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): <!-- <p align="center"><img src="advertisement.gif"></p> -->
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): <fieldset><legend>Advertisements</legend>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): <p align="center">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): <script type="text/javascript"><!--
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9043996592502243";
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): /* 000webhost Error Big */
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): google_ad_slot = "1420565520";
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): google_ad_width = 336;
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): google_ad_height = 280;
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): //-->
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): </script>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): <script type="text/javascript"
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): </script>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): </p>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770): </fieldset>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     <h3>1500 MB disk space, 100 GB data transfer! PHP, MySQL, FTP, cPanel..</h3>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     <p>Our free hosting service is supercharged with over 60 features, just like paid hosting. Unrestricted access to PHP, MySQL, FTP, cPanel, Website Builder and many more features are waiting for you absolutely free!</p>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     <h3>Need unlimited premium hosting that is really UNLIMITED?</h3>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     <p>Signup with <a href='http://www.hosting24.com/'>www.hosting24.com</a> - <b>unlimited</b> disk space, <b>unlimited</b> data transfer, host <b>unlimited</b> domains for just $4.84</p>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):     <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="dblue">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td> </td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><strong>&raquo; Free Hosting</strong></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td><div align="center"><strong>&raquo; Premium Hosting</strong></div></td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="40%">Price</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="30%">$0.00</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="30%">$4.84 / month</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="40%">Disk Space</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="30%">1500 MB</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="30%">Unlimited Disk Space!</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="40%">Data Transfer</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="30%">100 GB / month</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td width="30%">Unlimited Data Transfer!</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Add-on Domains</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>5</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Unlimited</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Sub-domains</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>5</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Unlimited</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>E-mail Addresses</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>5</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Unlimited</td>
06-28 21:05:56.610: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>MySQL Databases</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>2</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Unlimited</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Free domain registration yourname.COM, .NET, .ORG, .INFO, .CO.UK</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Control Panel</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Custom Panel</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>cPanel Pro, <a href="http://x3demob.cpx3demo.com:2082/login/?user=x3demob&pass=x3demob" target="_blank">see demo</a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td height="40"> </td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.000webhost.com/order.php"><img src="images/ordernow1.gif" width="89" height="25" border="0" /></a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/ordernow1.gif" alt="Web Hosting" width="89" height="25" border="0" /></a></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Site Builder</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Advanced Site Builder</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>      
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Assistance in  Installing Your Scripts</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Help in Developing Your Website</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Backups</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Automated Weekly Backups</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Limited</td>
06-28 21:05:56.615: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>      
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Uptime</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>99%</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>99.9%</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>FTP Accounts</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>1</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Unlimited</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Anonymous FTP Access</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>CGI Scripts</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td>PHP</td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.620: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Ruby On Rails</td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td>SSH Access</td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Perl</td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts">
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td> ASP.NET</td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       <tr class="list_accounts2">
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td>Python</td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/uncheck.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):         <td><img src="images/check.gif" width="15" height="15" /></td>
06-28 21:05:56.625: I/System.out(19770):       </tr>
06-28 21:05:56.630: I/System.out(19770): </div>
06-28 21:05:56.630: I/System.out(19770): </body>
06-28 21:05:56.630: I/System.out(19770): </html>



httppost= new HttpPost("http://31.170.160.102/public_html/check.php");
```

`31.170.160.102` this is my ip I get from my free host.

`/public_html/check.php` in the file manager root there is public_html folder I added it check.php.

This is check.php:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="mysql12.000webhost.com";
$database_localhost ="a6901827_justed";
$username_localhost ="a6901827_moudiz";
$password_localhost ="*****";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
if($rows == 0) { 
    echo "No Such User Found"; 
}
else  {
    echo "User Found"; 
}
?>
```

This is my code:

```
void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://31.170.160.102/public_html/check.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int responseStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Response : " + responseStatusCode); 

        Log.d("Http response: ", "> " + response);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        //    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: In logcat trace it doesn't look like error, it looks like HTML page printed to System.out

Comment: @Max77 why I am having such error ? I should have different results

Comment: As an aside, your PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @MattGibson I am just following a tutorial , on how to connect to the server , so I guess its a simple code . anyway how should I know what the reaseaon of the html ?

Comment: What did you expect to see? You see HTML page, from this line of code: System.out.println("Response : " + response);

Comment: @max77 the goal of this turoail to insert data in the database but i am not able to do that

Comment: In your snippets there's no code for inserting in database, only querying. Can you post link to this tutorial?

Comment: @Max77 this is the [tutorial](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/22/create-simple-login-form-php-android-connect-php-android/) your help is much appreciat . I have been stuck on this for 2 days. I can give you also the host credatianls  if you want to check soething, its a free host just testing my app on it

Answer (score 0):

The reason is these two lines

```
Log.d("Http response: ", "> " + response);
System.out.println("Response : " + response);
```

Also, clearly not an error as designated by the `I` in the logcat. That means `INFO`.

```
I/System.out(19770):
```

An error would be `E/<message>`. I assume all these lines are also followed by `D/<some_other_stuff>`, which would be `DEBUG` from the `Log.d` line - and again, not an error.